# How to do event-driven disk IO in C

Tags: c, io, event-handling

I am writing a C code to access a file steam and print it's content line by line (in fact, it is a std stream of a process which has been popen()-ed). I have came up with an sss (simple still stupid) way to access the file:

```
static int this_event_handler(struct msg) {

...


    pFile = popen ("some command");
    while ( fgets (mystring , 100 , pFile) != NULL ) {
        puts (mystring);
    }

...

}
```

I know that this code blocks the event loop and future messages to the server won't be useful. So, is there a good way to handle this without blocking the event loop?

For example I am looking for a method that listens to the stream like event driven and emits an event whenever a new line is written/readable (without creating a new thread).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new thread to read the file's content which won't block your event loop. Here's the thread start function:

```
void* put_msg(void* arg) {
    File *pFile = (File*)arg;
    mystring[100];
    while ( fgets (mystring , 100 , pFile) != NULL ) {
        puts (mystring);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Call it in your event handler, just after opening pFile:

```
pthread_t pid;
pthread_create(&pid, NULL, &put_msg, (void*)pFile);
```

Comment: I think I had to mention that without creating a new thread. This program is event-based and starting a new thread is not favourable.

Comment: You can try [Linux aio](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/aio.7.html). This will return immediately.

Comment: There's no conflict between event-driven logic and new thread. A new thread or getting a thread from a thread pool will let your code going on without blocking. Have you tried it? Or just your thought?

Comment: yes there is no conflict, but whenever we start a thread, the OS devotes some resources to it, specially computational resources (CPU) which is not good. In this example, the file is going to be updated once in a few seconds, but a new thread checks it every few milliseconds. It means that using a thread is thousands of times heavier than handling the job event-driven

Comment: So you could maintain a thread pool instead of creating a new thread. Or just push this task to a task queue, and pre-prepared worker threads pull tasks from this queue.

Comment: if I start a new thread, some resources will be allocated to that thread and it will start using the cpu. this is the main idea behind event-driven! and don't forget that if 2000 users request this service, 2000 threads will be started on the server!